# replace true false %in%

Tags: r, replace, boolean

I have a dataframe with numbers going from 1 to 10 in the second column:
[image]

Yet there are some numbers missing (2,5,7,9). For missing numbers, I would like to have "NA". I have achieved this by the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(group=as.integer(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)), numbers_with_gaps=as.integer(c(1,3,4,6,8,10)))
numbers_with_gaps <- df$numbers_with_gaps
numbers_complete <- c(1:10)

true_false_vector <- numbers_complete %in% numbers_with_gaps
numbers_complete[true_false_vector == FALSE] <- NA
```

So in the end, this vector should have 10 entries:
[image]

My problem is that I would like to have these "NA" values also for the first column of the data frame above. Unfortunately "applying" the true false vector to the whole data frame does not work. Which function could be useful to achieve my goal?

Comment: What is `T_F_vector`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I corrected it. It should be "true_false_vector".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyverse` to utilize `complete` from `tidyr`. Then use the `NA` from `group` to set them also in `numbers_with_gaps`, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 complete(numbers_with_gaps = seq(10)) %>% 
 mutate(numbers_with_gaps = replace(numbers_with_gaps, is.na(group), NA))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 2
>    numbers_with_gaps group
>                <int> <int>
>  1                 1     1
>  2                NA    NA
>  3                 3     1
>  4                 4     1
>  5                NA    NA
>  6                 6     2
>  7                NA    NA
>  8                 8     2
>  9                NA    NA
> 10                10     2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(group=as.integer(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)), numbers_with_gaps=as.integer(c(1,3,4,6,8,10)))
numbers_with_gaps <- df$numbers_with_gaps
numbers_complete <- c(1:10)

true_false_vector <- numbers_complete %in% numbers_with_gaps

df[which(true_false_vector == FALSE),] <- NA
```